# How to get pymodbus to correctly communicate with PLC?

Tags: python, pymodbus, pymodbustcp

Before I ask, I just want to mention that I have spent a few days researching this and can't seem to find my way out of this basic issue. I have read the docs and spent time here. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked.

I have inherited a massive monolithic python program that successfully reads holding registers with pymodbus + `read_holding_registers`. I have spent time editing python before but have never really learned it. To try and understand this on the python side, I have tried writing my own basic program from scratch. I started big and eventually broke the code down to as simple as I can.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient('192.168.1.98', port=502)
client.connect()

rr = client.read_holding_registers(10904, 2)

print rr

client.close()
```

I know that this is the register I want. It's a holding register on a Horner PLC. It's well-documented in both the python program and in Horner CSCAPE. But whenever I run the program, it just prints whatever value I put in the second item of the tuple. So here, it will just print `2`. If I supply a tuple of `(10905, 1)` it just prints `1`. The true value of the register bit is supposed to be `0`.

I would post the massive program, but it is private unfortunately. This is python2.7. I know it's bad but I just want to catch up on understanding the program before I worry about porting it to 3.9.

Comment: Did you try `rr = client.read_holding_registers(10904, 2).registers` ?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I swear I couldn't piece this together from the documentation I could find anywhere! How do I thank you with flair?

Comment: You're welcome! I will turn the comment in an answer then, just for sake of completeness

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it with `.registers` like this

`rr = client.read_holding_registers(10904, 2).registers`

Also, if you check [the documentation](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html), the author claims that the code is compatible with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x so that you can port it.